# Could not resolve matching constructor for repository

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, maven, spring-boot

I try to run project with mongodb but receive error:

> Error creating bean with name 'IUserRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

Code of MongoConfig:

```
package MediaServerFacade.Public.Data.repository;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import com.mongodb.Mongo;

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class MongoConfig {
    @Bean
    public MongoFactoryBean mongo(){
        MongoFactoryBean mongo = new MongoFactoryBean();
        mongo.setHost("localhost");
        return mongo;
    }
    @Bean
    public MongoOperations mongoTemplate(Mongo mongo){
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo, "LearnPlace");
    }
}
```

Code of IUserRepository:

```
package MediaServerFacade.Public.Data.repository;

import java.util.UUID;


import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import MediaServerFacade.Public.Data.User;

public interface IUserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, UUID>{
    public User getById(UUID id);
    public void update(User entity) ;
    public void delete(UUID id) ;
    public void insert(User entity) ;
    public Iterable<User> getAll() ;
    public long count();

}
```

User repository implementation:

```
package MediaServerFacade.Public.Data.repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;

import MediaServerFacade.Public.Data.User;

public class UserRepository  implements IUserRepository{
    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations _mongoOperations;   

    @Override
    public User getById(UUID id) {
        return _mongoOperations.findById(id, User.class);       
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User entity) {
        Update update = new Update();       
        _mongoOperations.updateFirst(Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(entity.getId())), update, User.class);        
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(UUID id) {
        _mongoOperations.remove(Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id)));     
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(User entity) {
        _mongoOperations.insert(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<User> getAll() {
        return _mongoOperations.findAll(User.class);
    }

    @Override
    public long count() {       
        return _mongoOperations.getCollection("users").count();
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends User> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entites) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll(Sort sort) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Page<User> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends User> S save(S entity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public User findOne(UUID id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists(UUID id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<User> findAll(Iterable<UUID> ids) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(User entity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Iterable<? extends User> entities) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Content of pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>MediaServerFacade</groupId>
   <artifactId>Public</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-172186a1-66e2-4a96-acac-f35fa6fe587d</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>Public</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <version.spring.mongodb>1.4.0.RELEASE</version.spring.mongodb>         
      <demo.port>8083</demo.port>
      <!-- Main class -->
      <start-class>MediaServerFacade.Public.App</start-class>   
   </properties>
   <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
   <dependencies>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
      </dependency>
         <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.kurento</groupId>
         <artifactId>kurento-client</artifactId>
      </dependency>   
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
         <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
               <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <tarLongFileMode>posix</tarLongFileMode>
               <archive>
                  <manifest>
                     <mainClass>MediaServerFacade.Public.App</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
               </archive>
               <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
               <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
               <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
               <path>/mediaserver</path>
               <update>true</update>
               <ignorePackaging>true</ignorePackaging>
               <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
               <username>admin</username>
               <password>r06d0288</password>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <profiles>
      <profile>
         <id>default</id>
         <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
         </activation>
         <build>
            <plugins>
               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                     <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
                     <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                     <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                  </configuration>
                  <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                     </execution>
                  </executions>
               </plugin>
               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                  <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                           <tasks>
                              <copy file="${project.build.directory}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-bin.zip" tofile="${project.build.directory}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip" />
                           </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                     </execution>
                  </executions>
               </plugin>
               <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
               <layout>ZIP</layout>
               <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>repackage</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </build>
      </profile>
      <profile>
         <id>no-assembly</id>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kurento</groupId>
            <artifactId>kurento-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.2</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.32</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

And I try to use that repository as:

```
 @Autowired
  private IUserRepository repository;
```

My applicationContext.xml is empty. What else should I do to run project correctly?

Comment: Some of the method you have defined in your interface/implementing class are already provided by MongoRepository class. Furthermore if you want to add any custom method using mongoTemplate, then you have to follow spring repository rules. So create another interface with name UserRepositoryCustom(having custom methods), and implement those methods in a class with name UserRepositoryImpl.

Comment: Also add @Repository annotation to UserRepository class

Comment: in IUserRepository : public interface IUserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, UUID>{} use String not UUID

Comment: Thanks for your replies. But the problem is stil exist. I added @Repository annotation and changed UUID to String.